# How to conditionally include a filter in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have a component where I am mapping through an array of items. I am adding a filter to it as well. Right now it looks like this:

```
{data.products                  
  .filter((item) => item.acf.quiz.gender.some(({ value }) => value === state.theme.quiz.quizGender))
  .map((item, id) => {
    return <ProductCard key={id} item={item} data={data} />;
  })
}
```

So if the gender has been set to state by a radio button in another component, the map will filter by items where that gender is an attribute. I have that part working just fine.

What I am trying to figure out though, is if there is a way to conditionally apply that filter, so that if the use didn't set their gender, then the filter would not apply. I know there is a way to do this outside of the map, but I am needing to do it inline with this `.filter()` as there will be several more filters that I will need to apply.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Just have the filter function return true if gender is an empty array. You might also check for undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as long as the non selection state is null/undefined/false you can just add a check inside the filter

```
.filter((item) => 
  !state.theme.quiz.quizGender || 
  item.acf.quiz.gender.some(({ value }) => 
    value === state.theme.quiz.quizGender)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a check to see if `item.acf.quiz.gender` has a value, if yes then continue with the operation else, return `false`

```
{
  data.products
    .filter((item) =>
      item.acf.quiz.gender
        ? item.acf.quiz.gender.some(
            ({ value }) => value === state.theme.quiz.quizGender
          )
        : false
    )
    .map((item, id) => {
      return <ProductCard key={id} item={item} data={data} />;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return true on the filter if `state` isn't set :

```js
{
    data.products
        .filter((item) => 
            !state?.theme?.quiz?.quizGender
            || item.acf.quiz.gender.some(({
                    value
                }) => value === state.theme.quiz.quizGender)
        )
        .map((item, id) => {
            return <ProductCard key = {id} item={item} data={data} />;
        })
}
```